# Add delay between retries when origin is down (Nginx, 502)

Tags: nginx, proxy, delay

Pretty much the tile. Got a node app behind nginx, and when i restart the app i would like nginx to delay the response, and retry doing the request a couple of times with some delay inbetween. Everything that i found would only instantly retry N times, but that obviously is no useful when the app is down for a restart, which is my use-case. Is there some way? I dont even care how hacky it is / if it  is, i just need a solution that is not starting a second instance of the app, and killing the first one when the second one started.

Thanks!

Comment: Post the config you have used as of now

Answer (score 1):

You can using a module:

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/echo

Basically, you serve regular requests on `server_one` upstream; if it fails with 502, code is intercepted, then request is passed to `@delay`, it waits 5 seconds (in this example) and then request is again passed to `@delayed` wich passes it to `server_two` upstream.

```
upstream server_one {
    server 172.16.0.1;
}
 
upstream server_two {
    server 172.16.0.2;
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://server_one;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 502 @delay;
    }
 
    location @delay {
        echo_sleep 5; // sleep here
        echo_exec @delayed;
    }

    location @delayed {
        proxy_pass http://server_two;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add same server as multiple upstream and configure `proxy_next_upstream`, `proxy_next_upstream_timeout` and `proxy_next_upstream_tries` options as well. [Reference](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_next_upstream)

```
    upstream node_servers {
        server 127.0.0.1:12005;
        server 127.0.0.1:12005;
    }

    ...

    proxy_next_upstream http_502;
    proxy_next_upstream_timeout 60;
    proxy_next_upstream_tries 3;
```

However, I would recommend you to use process managers like `pm2` which support graceful reload/restart. They are relevant if you are using more than one CPU for your nodejs server in a clustered mode.

Comment: I've tried it this exact way, the problem is that nginx just completely ignores any delay that i set for it when the app is down, thus port not used, it simply instantly tries all upstreams that i define. The way that i've done it now is that i've created a second node app which acts as a reverse proxy w/ an exponential backoff, and set that as the second upstream. This way when the app itself is down, the "backup" app will try to request it until its back, and then returns the result. Not sure if thats dumb, or genius, but it does exactly what i want ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: 5 years later, still an issue. Btw `pm2` does not appear to have a graceful reload on `--watch`, which seems like a common use case. Just an abrupt restart.